# After using the tab key, can’t scroll to the top

Tags: javascript, android, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

When using the tab key or the next button on an device keyboard the scroll seems to get out off sync.

Use the following steps to reproduce this:

1.Have an form with more fields then fits the screen
Tab through the fields until the field which is not visible gets the focus.

2.Now try to reach the the top of the page with the mouse
It keeps scrolling back to the wrong position.

To make it easier I forked an existing codepen and edited to show the problem.
LINK:  [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbgpQg2)

This happens on all devices i have. Android 4.4.3 and also Android 5.0.1.
Also tested at the latest `v1.0.0-rc.0` off `ionic`.

Comment: Your codepen doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your codepen so I share a solution that I used on my application, you should add $ionicScrollDelegate to your controller, here is an example:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $ionicScrollDelegate) {
    ...

    $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop();

    ...
}
```